# How to configure weekly incremental AWS Appflows to overwrite former files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS Appflow to transfer files from a SharePoint to a S3 bucket, configured to run weekly and only make an incremental transfer of changed files.

I did not found a way to make Appflow overwrite files with changes, instead to creates a subfolder each type named after the ID of each AppFlow weekly run.

I have read the documentation talking about [partitioning and aggerating data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/flows-partition.html#partition-procedure) and former answers on Stack Overflow mentionned them, but it seems these functionalities are no longer available.

Thanks in advance